# ValueError: The view platformapp.views.loginfunc didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

djangoを使ってアプリ開発をしている学生です。views.pyのコードを書いている中で、どうしても解決できないエラーが発生したので、是非プロフェッショナルの皆様の力を貸していただきたいです。まだプログラミング経験は浅く、専門用語等分からないところもありますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

以下のコードを作成し実行した結果、エラーが発生してしまいました。
どのように解決すればよいでしょうか？

**views.pyのコード**

```
# coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Create your views here.

def signupfunc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username2 = request.POST['username']
        password2 = request.POST['password']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username2)
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'error':'このユーザーは登録されています'})
        except:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username2, '', password2)
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'some':100})
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'some':100})

def loginfunc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username2 = request.POST['username']
        password2 = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username2, password=password2)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('signup')   
        else:
            return redirect('signup')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
ValueError at /login/
The view platformapp.views.loginfunc didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://localhost:8000/login/
Django Version:
1.11.27
Exception Type:
ValueError
Exception Value:
The view platformapp.views.loginfunc didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location:
/home/yuki/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 198
Python Executable:
/usr/bin/python
Python Version:
2.7.17
Python Path:
['/mnt/c/Users/yuuki/platform/platformproject',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/yuki/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time:
Sat, 25 Jan 2020 07:18:31 +0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

発生しているエラー `The view platformapp.views.loginfunc didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` は、 `loginfunc` 関数がNoneを返した、と言っています。

しかし、ソースコードを見た限りでは、 `render` と `redirect` はHttpResponse（かその継承クラス）を返すため、Noneが返されるケースはなさそうに見えます。

このため、以下の可能性が考えられます。

1. 別の.pyファイルの loginfunc が使われている -> 確認してみてください
2. コード修正後にDjangoを再起動していない -> 再起動してみてください
3. `views.py` ディレクトリにある `__pycache__` ディレクトリを削除してDjangoを再起動したら直る

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！　2番ではないので、1番か3番だろうと思うのですが、1番はどうやって確認すればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 期待する実装コードが確実に実行されていることを調べてみて下さい。loggerやprintでなにか出力するプリントデバッグや、raise RuntimeError('test') というコードで強制的にエラーにしてみる、といった方法があります。